# How to change string columns size for all columns in pandas hdfstore?

Tags: pandas

How can the min_itemsize for **all** string columns be changed in a hdf5 table? I don't know my dataframe structure during run time, and thus can not hardcode it.

Answer (score 3):

see the docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#string-columns).

The itemsize is created on the first append (and cannot be changed later). If `min_itemsize`
is not specified it will be the max length of strings in that append.

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame({ 'A' : ['foo','bar']})

In [2]: store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5',mode='w')

In [3]: store.append('df',df,min_itemsize=30)

In [4]: store.get_storer('df')
Out[4]: frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->2,ncols->1,indexers->[index])

In [5]: store.get_storer('df').table
Out[5]: 
/df/table (Table(2,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "values_block_0": StringCol(itemsize=30, shape=(1,), dflt='', pos=1)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (1724,)
  autoindex := True
  colindexes := {
    "index": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False}

In [8]: store['df']
Out[8]: 
     A
0  foo
1  bar

In [6]: store.close()
```